# How to create an arraylist and add it to nested arraylist?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my grammar I'm not really good at english and I want to learn in android/java sqlitedatabase

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> storage;
ArrayList<String> where;
while (c.moveToNext()) {
            where.add(c.getString(0));
            where.add(c.getString(1));
            where.add(c.getString(2));
            where.add(c.getString(3));
            where.add(c.getString(4));
            where.add(c.getString(5));
            storage.add(where); 



        }
```

It only display the 1st row in database.
Example I have 2 rows in database

```
Boy   -  Girl    -Car
Tall     Small    New
Small    Small    Old

I want to add them in a arraylist which is variable "where"
and I want where add to Arralist storage in arraylist form
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create an ArrayList? `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Show a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I edit it I hope you understand my example :(

Comment: `where` is never initialized in your example, and even if it were, you need to either clear it or reinitialize it every loop, otherwise you'll just end up with duplicate entries.

Comment: it always duplicate the entries , how can I reinitialize every loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess following code is what you need.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> storage = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> where;
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   where = new ArrayList<String>();
   where.add(c.getString(0));
   where.add(c.getString(1));
   where.add(c.getString(2));
   where.add(c.getString(3));
   where.add(c.getString(4));
   where.add(c.getString(5));
   storage.add(where); 
}
```

Comment: If it helps you,please choose my answer and up vote it,that will be appreciated.